# What IP rating for bathroom downlighters?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, uk

I recently had a bathroom refurb done and the electrician put IP rated downlighters in the ceiling (chrome bezelled spotlights). I don't recall if they were IP44 or IP65.

Separately, I'm replacing some spotlights in another bathroom myself (from old halogen to LED) and the existing downlighters are most certainly not IP rated (or they're IP20).

I'd only envisaged replacing the bulbs and bulb holders, but should I replace the downlighters with IP-rated ones? If so, what rating?

I don't have a problem buying or fitting new ones, but I notice that IP rated downlighters have a much narrower angle of light and the bathroom only has three spots for quite a large room. I don't want to make it darker, and I'm not keen to add more spots.

Regarding zones: The ceiling spots are outside zone 2, being about 2.5 metres from the floor. They're not directly above a shower or sink either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guide is

- Submerged IPX7
- Above a tub or shower IPX5
- Beside a tub or a shower IPX4
- Elsewhere in the bathroom - unrated

**But I would still put in IP44 in the unrated zone as there can be a fair bit of moisture and condensation.**  Personally, I try to put in stainless steel versions of fittings if possible.

Source for Nz and Oz [Bathroom Zones](https://plumbline.co.nz/electrical-bathroom-products-information)

Source for USA [WHAT ARE IP RATINGS – AND WHICH ONES DO I NEED FOR MY BATHROOM LIGHTING?](https://thelightyard.com/blogs/the-blog-of-light/what-are-ip-ratings-and-which-ones-do-i-need-for-my-bathroom-lighting)

Comment: I'm in the UK, but I take your point that you'd recommend IP44. I'm not sure how IP ratings translate to ingress from steam (as opposed to liquid water splashes/jets etc..) but actually the IP65 products aren't much more expensive and light beam angle seems the same. Fingers cross it's not too much dimmer, or I'll be cutting more holes

Answer (score 2):

These are the IP ratings from BS7671 for the UK:
[image: Bathroom zones]
([source](https://electriciancourses4u.co.uk/useful-resources/ip-ratings-explained/))

As well as the requirement for IP rating in zones 0 and 1, there is also a condition on SELV (low voltage):

> Zone 0 – No switchgear allowed. 12V SELV equipment can be used as long as the safety source is outside of the zones

> Zone 1 – Only 12V SELV switchgear is allowed to be used as long as the safety source is outside the zones. 25V SELV and PELV equipment can be used as long as the safety source is outside the zones.

(the 'safety source' being the transformer or similar)

Answer (score -2):

led lights dont need protection against moist cuz its low voltage----max 12V...halogen...led is 3-5 volt... so there is no chance ypu can get zapped....need 30mA breaker in circuit. and as they are mounted over 2M no zone...

edit : Im located in Norway and my dayjobb is as an electrician, so European rules apply. Norway use 230V IT    & 400V TN

"thinking logic"
Main reason its not a problem. And same goes for all Electrics
as long as it is >50V ,skin Resistanse 1MOhm ,breaker 30mA.
use Ohms law U = R x I  .... the math  tells us the skin resistanse is to big... so we are safe under 50V, halogen has a heat problem you need to have in mind.

more elaborated in link below.

https://www.thelightingsuperstore.co.uk/bathroom-lighting-zones

Comment: You still want IP/wet location rated fixtures even at 12VDC -- if nothing else, it'll keep them from getting roached by galvanic corrosion

Comment: OP doesn't specify, but it's common for LED bulbs to run at mains voltage. Obviously they contain circuitry inside the bulb to step down from mains AC to low voltage DC; but externally the wiring is all at mains voltage.

Comment: They will indeed be mains voltage at the fitting. As you say, DC driver being in the bulbs.

Comment: Led tech are moving fast these days. led fittings today do not have any serviceable parts.  no bulb.

Comment: There are plenty of downlighters on the market here that aren't integrated. i.e. for replaceable bulbs.

Comment: a bulb  is a light source halogen glow led  its the same. A down light is not , its a lamp or fitting.

Comment: I don't know what point or terminology you're arguing here, but [these are the "downlighters"](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Saxby-GU10-Chrome-Effect-IP65-Cast-Fixed-Downlight---5W/p/213331) I have in my bathroom that take replaceable LED "lamps" often called "bulbs".